# code blocks + gcc + debian (amd64) linker error: undefined references

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

I am getting an undefined reference error when trying to link my application with code blocks and command line gcc. The file giving the error has the function prototype in the header. The source file the function the linker is complaining about has other functions in it that aren't giving this error. I copied and pasted the function declarator to the header and calling function (fixing the parameters of course) to ensure it is not a typo. What am I missing? Other functions called from linked_list.c don't give me linker errors.

Here are the code snippets:

mw_proxy.h:

```
struct addr_l_node
{
    uint32_t address;
    struct addr_l_node *next;
};
...
typedef struct addr_l_node addr_l_node;
...
void delete_addr_list(addr_l_node *first);
```

parse_config.c:

```
#include "mw_proxy.h"
...
addr_l_node *first;
...
delete_addr_list(first);
```

linked_list.c:

```
void delete_addr_list(addr_l_node *first)
{
...
}
```

Finally I am getting this error from code blocks:

```
obj/Debug/parse_config.o||In function `parse_config':|
/media/sf_H_DRIVE/src/codeblocks/mw_proxy/parse_config.c|240|undefined reference to `delete_addr_list'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

From a bash shell:

```
gcc  int_array.o cleanup.o check_datagram.o mw_proxy.o parse_config.o linked_list.o 
parse_config.o: In function `parse_config':
/media/sf_H_DRIVE/src/codeblocks/mw_proxy/parse_config.c:240: undefined reference to `delete_addr_list'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with how code blocks is building it. gcc *.c in the source directory works. I will try to compile them into object files from the command line, then link the object files and see what happens.

Comment: Confirmed. It is code blocks. I was just able to compile and link from a shell with no problems. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong with code blocks?